# How to reduce mean ignore padded rows in 3D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have and a 3D tensor `A` has shape `(batch_size, N, dim)` and a 3D tensor `B` has shape `(batch_size, N, 2)`. In which `B` has some padding row to fill to N (which is not a zero vector, as it already passed in some functions). To know which row is padded, I have to look up tensor `B`, if row `k` is padded, the value at the `k`-row in tensor `B` is `[0, 0]`. I want to filter out these padded rows in `A` before calculating the mean.

After reducing A to its mean along `dim=1`, the result has a shape of `(batch_size, dim)`.

Edit: I figured out one solution. Any other solution is welcome!

```
# squeeze to 2D
A = A.view(-1, A.size(-1))
B = B.view(-1, B.size(-1))

# mask out padded row
mask = torch.sum(B, dim=-1)
mask[mask!=0] = 1

# the point is I need to assign padded row in A by zero
A = mask.unsqueeze(-1)*A

# calculate the real size of each cluster. 
mask = mask.view(batch_size, -1)
batch_cluster_size = torch.sum(mask, dim=-1, keepdim=True)

# convert back to original shape
A = A.view(batch_size, -1, A.size(-1))

output = torch.sum(A, dim=1)/batch_cluster_size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more compact version uses [`torch.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.any.html) to check if the row is padded and avoids broadcasting the tensors to different shapes:

```
>>> mask = B.any(dim=-1)                 # (bs, N)
>>> A *= mask.unsqueeze(-1)              # (bs, N, dim)
>>> output = A.sum(1)/mask.sum(1, True)  # (bs, dim)
```

Comment: I tried and this dont work. I dont think torch.all can check the row is padded or not.

Comment: You should use `torch.any` instead, *ie.* if at least one element in a row is non-zero, then it's not a padded row.

Comment: Let me know if it is working now!

Comment: Yes, It works now, thank you for correcting my question too T.T